# I have an array of image URL's - what's the best way to display them in HTML using Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have an array `thumbnails` that contains the path to several images. I'm trying to use masonry to display them in a grid using Vue, but I'm having trouble getting the result I want.

This is what I came up with:

```
<ul v-for="thumbnail in thumbnails" class="masonry">
    <li v-html="thumbnail" class="masonry-brick"></li>
</ul>
```

But that compiles to this:

```
<ul class="masonry">
    <li class="masonry-brick">
        <img src="images/thumbnail1.jpg">
    </li>
</ul>
<ul class="masonry">
    <li class="masonry-brick">
        <img src="images/thumbnail2.jpg">
    </li>
</ul>
```

when what I want is something like this:

```
<ul class="masonry">
    <li class="masonry-brick">
        <img src="images/thumbnail1.jpg">
    </li>
    <li class="masonry-brick">
        <img src="images/thumbnail2.jpg">
    </li>
</ul>
```

---

I'm also wondering if it'd be better to do away with `<img>` altogether and instead set the background-image of the `<li>`'s - I'm just not sure the best way to go about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `v-for` attribute causes the element it's on to be repeated, so you need to put it on the `li` rather than the `ul`.

Loop the `li` element instead:

```html
<ul class="masonry">
    <li
       v-for="(thumbnail, index) in thumbnails"
       :key="index"
       v-html="thumbnail"
       class="masonry-brick"
    >
    </li>
</ul>
```

As for the image check the official documentation.